# Pasting row from one sheet to the other to first blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen some examples but they have been using .Select and .Activate. I am trying to learn how to not use those anymore because everyone says you should try to stay away from them.

I want to take a row, then copy it to the first blank row on the other sheet. I was close but it just isn't working.

```
UsdRws = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


With Sheets("Totals by Department")
    .Range("A1:Z" & UsdRws).autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1450"
    .Range("A2:Z" & UsdRws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.COPY
End With


Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)


Sheets(2).NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set NextRow = Nothing
```

The first part copies perfectly, I really just need help pasting it over on the other sheet. I will also take other recommendations for cleaning the code up. Like I said I am trying to learn to write better. The second part is messy because I have been adding and editing it but now I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "NextRow" object is a Range object, but you are calling it as if it were a method or property of Sheets(2).

Try removing the Sheets(2). and just start with Next Row.

```
Set NextRow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: It looks like it pasted right over where I copied. It won't go over to the other sheet. Do I have to actually select it? or activate it?

Comment: I just edited this, try it again. Your original code doesn't qualify which sheet NextRow belongs to, so Excel is automatically setting it to ActiveSheet. By qualifying this as Sheets(2).Range, it will copy to the right sheet.

Comment: Thanks! worked great! Right before I am about to leave work. Now I won't be thinking about it all night haha

Answer (score 0):

```
' UsdRws is equal the last used row on whichever sheet is active at the moment that this code runs 

UsdRws = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' this code properly references ranges on a specific worksheet, regardless of which worksheet is active

With Sheets("Totals by Department")
    .Range("A1:Z" & UsdRws).autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1450"
    .Range("A2:Z" & UsdRws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.COPY
End With

' NextRow is reference to a cell on whichever sheet is active at the moment that this code runs
' but the row referenced is same as the first emply cell on Sheets(2) 

Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

' NextRow is already a range .... so it should be NextRow.PasteSpecial ......

Sheets(2).NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set NextRow = Nothing
```

this may be what you want

```
With Sheets("Totals by Department")
    UsdRws = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:Z" & UsdRws).autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1450"
    .Range("A2:Z" & UsdRws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.COPY
End With

Set NextRow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set NextRow = Nothing
```